# List all the elements of the subgroup of Möbius transformations preserving the set $\{0, 1 + i, \infty\}$

Tags: group-theory, complex-analysis, group-isomorphism

List all the elements of the the subgroup $M_{\{0, 1, \infty\}}$ of the group of Möbius transformations, preserving the set $\{0, 1, \infty\}$ and give an explicit isomorphism $M_{\{0, 1, \infty\}} = S_3$. Using this, list all the elements of the subgroup $M_{\{0, 1 + i, \infty\}}$ of Möbius transformations preserving the set $\{0, 1 + i, \infty\}$, together with an explicit isomorphism.

I have done the beginning bit I am unsure how to map $M_{\{0, 1, \infty\}}$ and $M_{\{0, 1 + i, \infty\}}$ to each other.

Answer (score 1):

There is a unique Möbius transformation $g$ which sends $0$ to $a$, $1$ to $b$, and $\infty$ to $c$ (provided $a$, $b$, and $c$ are distinct). Given $f \in M_{\{0, 1, \infty\}}$, note that $g\circ f\circ g^{-1} \in M_{\{a, b, c\}}$. So consider the map

\begin{align*}
\Phi: M_{\{0, 1, \infty\}} &\to M_{\{a, b, c\}}\\
f &\mapsto g\circ f \circ g^{-1}.
\end{align*}

You should show that $\Phi$ is a bijection. Also, depending on what you've seen, you may need to justify the existence of $g$.

Comment: I'm still unsure what to do.

Comment: What does $g\circ f$ do to the points $0$, $1$, and $\infty$?

Comment: go to the identity?

Comment: No. What is $(g\circ f)(0) = g(f(0))$?

Comment: Im unsure my notes doesnt contain anything like this

Comment: You don't need your notes. Given that $f \in M_{\{0, 1, \infty\}}$, what is $f(0)$?

Comment: 0?how does this help me to work out how to map them?

Comment: Correct. Because $f(0) = 0$, $(g\circ f)(0) = g(f(0)) = g(0) = a$. Likewise $(g\circ f)(1) = b$ and $(g\circ f)(\infty) = c$. If we could find a Möbius transformation $h$ which sent $a$ to $0$, $b$ to $1$ and $c$ to $\infty$, then we would have $g\circ f\circ h \in M_{\{a, b, c\}}$. The mapping that you desire would then be $M_{\{0, 1, \infty\}} \to M_{\{a, b, c\}}$, $f \mapsto g\circ f\circ h$. Can you see how $h$ is related to $g$?

Comment: do you have to do L^-1xMxL?

Comment: Well, it depends how you define $L$ and $M$, but conjugation is definitely the idea. I will edit my answer to include some more details.

Comment: Im this case L^-1 = (1+i)z and L is z/(1+i)

Comment: If you are going to use that $L$, you would need $M \mapsto L\circ M\circ L^{-1}$; this gives a map $M_{\{0, 1, \infty\}} \to M_{\{0, 1+i, \infty\}}$.